# Handling different session profiles in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm developing a system and have different profiles with the same View Page just the information is different regarding to the user information, so when a specific user login, this user can open your user profile but other guest user just can see some specific information because is not the owner of the profile.

For example:

- mysite.com/user/user_1
- mysite.com/user/user_2

If the user_1 login, can see your full profile and if visit the profile of the user_2 just can see some information, and viceversa.

I can't apply the basic before auth filter because not only one user can login in the system.

I suppose that can't apply this basic auth, because if one user login can see all profiles and information just filtering the auth if is logged or not.

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('getProfile')));
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('getSettings')));
    ...
}

public function getProfile()
{

    $user_information = //get_from_database
    return $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile')
        ->with('user',$user_information);

}

public function getSettings()
{

    $user_information = //get_from_database
    return $this->layout->content = View::make('user.settings')
        ->with('user',$user_information);

}
```

So, I want to know if exists a way to do in Laravel.
Regards!

Comment: Add conditionings to your templates. E.g: `@if ($user->isMainUser()) ...`.

Comment: Well, yes.. is the first thing I thought, so.. doesn't exists a way of Laravel using filters or something like that?

Comment: Filters in Laravel are executed *before* and *after* requests and are a way to redirect business logic in the right direction. What you need is a way to *show/hide* parts of the template based on whether the user is a main user or a secondary user.

Comment: Is true, will implement conditions.. thanks!